# update record with the form - Codeigniter 2.1

Tags: codeigniter, crud

i have some problem with update in CI 2.1
I followed the user guide "mini-tut" for create e news, but i cant understand how to update a record with a form.

my update models is:

```
    // update dei record
public function update_news($id)
{
    $data = array(
        'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
        'slug' => $this->input->post('slug'),
        'text' => $this->input->post('text')
        );

    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('news', $data); 
}
```

how can i make the controller for update?? i try:

```
 public function update($id)
 {
  $this->load->helper('form');
  $this->load->library('form_validation');

  $data['title'] = 'Update an intem';

  $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('text', 'text', 'required');

  if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
  {
   $this->load->view('templates/header', $data); 
   $this->load->view('news/update');
   $this->load->view('templates/footer');
  }
 else
  {
   $this->news_model->update_news($id);
   $this->load->view('news/success');
  }
 }
```

but i display a 404() page...

the views for update is:

```
    <h2>Update an item</h2>

<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

<?php echo form_open('news/update') ?>

 <label for="title">Title</label> 
 <input type="input" name="title" /><br />

 <label for="slug">Slug</label> 
 <input type="input" name="slug" /><br />

 <label for="text">Text</label>
 <textarea name="text"></textarea><br />

 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update an item" /> 

</form>
```

any one can help me how do a "simnple" update for understand a CI logic?

Comment: Make sure you typed in the URL correctly and you follow the convention in CodeIgniter. Also, if you're using `mod_rewrite` for a cleaner URL, make sure the `RewriteRule` is configured correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you want, then you should just pass the $this->input->post(x) to the model from your controller.
I personally have been using it like this:

Controller:

```
$data = array(
   'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
   'text' => $this->input->post('text'),
   'slug' => $this->input->post('slug'),
);
if($this->my_model->exists($id)) {
    $this->my_model->update($id, $data);
} else {
    $this->my_model->insert($data);
}
```

And your Model should look like:

```
// update dei record
public function update($id, $data)
{
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('news', $data); 
}
```

Your controller uses the first segment as an argument of the controller method:

```
public function update($id)
```

You can also try using

```
$id = $this->uri->segment(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

//Controller
public function update($id)
    {
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

```
    $data['title'] = 'Update an intem';

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('text', 'text', 'required');
    $data['news'] = $this->news_model->get_news_by_id($id);


    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data); 
        $this->load->view('news/update', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->news_model->update_news($id);
        redirect('/news', 'refresh');
    }
}
```

---

//Model
public function update_news($id)
    {

```
    $data = array(
        'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
        'slug' => $this->input->post('title'),
        'text' => $this->input->post('text')
    );
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('news', $data);
}
```

---

View

```
<label for="title">Title</label>
<input type="input" name="title" value="<?php echo $news[0]['title'];?>" /><br />
<input type = "hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $news[0]['id'];?>" />
<label for="text">Text</label>
<textarea name="text"><?php echo $news[0]['text'];?></textarea><br />

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create news item" />
```

Comment: To help other people with similar problems generalize from your answer, it's ideal to include an explanation of why this solves the problem.

Answer (score -1):

To add  a page in code igniter

I will give you the example which i have done

Model:

```
function add()      
{        
   $name=$_POST['name'];        
   $department=$_POST['dept'];      
   $degree=$_POST['degree'];        
   $mark=$_POST['mark'];    

   $this->db->query("INSERT INTO `simple`(name,department,degree,mark) VALUES('$name','$department','$degree','$mark')");       
}
```

Controller:

```
public function add()   
{   
   $this->load->model('modd');      
   $this->modd->add();      
   $this->load->view('add');    
}
```

Views :

add.php

```
<form method="post" action="<?php base_url();?>index.php/contr/add">
    <table>
        <?php echo form_open('contr/add');?>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <td><input type="text" name="name" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Department</th>
            <td><input type="text" name="dept" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Degree</th>
            <td><input type="text" name="degree" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Marks</th>
            <td><input type="text" name="mark" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" name="add" value="Add" /></td>
        <?php echo form_close(); ?>
            <td>
                <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/contr/view"><input type="button" value="view" /></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: downvoting for SQL injection vulnerability